# Input text box not recognising local storage data

Tags: javascript, search, input, local-storage

I have a search input box that requires a location input in order to run a search, much like the Google geolocation API.

I have an address that I have saved in local storage that is derived from the user's location from the input box when they choose to save their location.
When pre-filling the value of the input box to the local storage data, the search input does not recognise this as a valid address. However, if I type the location in the exact same format of the local storage data the input box recognises this completely fine and works as expected. I am not sure why this input box does not like this pre-filled data as I can see this is of string type much like anything I might manually type in. Should I be changing the format of my local storage data in any way? Please note I am attempting to manipulate an existing input box on a web page, I don't have access to the HTML of the search box.

My code is as below:

```
 const saveLocation =
        `<div class="saveLocationWrap">
      <input type="checkbox" id="saveLocation" name="saveLocation">
      <label for="saveLocation">Save my location</label>
      </div>`

searchContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', saveLocation)

/// saveLocation box being the check box I have inserted on page
const saveLocationBox = document.querySelector('#saveLocation')
/// searchBox being the input field
const searchBox = document.querySelector('#locationTextbox')

      saveLocationBox.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (saveLocationBox.checked == true) {
          localStorage.setItem('location', searchBox.value)
        } else {
          console.log('unchecked')
        }
      })


if ('location' in localStorage) {
        searchBox.value = localStorage.getItem('location')
      }
```

This all works as expected as data from local storage is retrieved and pre filled into the existing search box. Problem arises when attempting to search as the input box does not recognise the data as a valid address.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `searchBox`? If its an input element why are you calling it like a function?

Comment: searchbox is the variable that contains the input element. I am calling it as a function because the code is wrapped within an IIFE. Calling it like usual variable doesn't seem to work either i.e. 
 
```if('location' in localStorage) {
        searchBox.value = localStorage.getItem('location')
      }```

Comment: We can't tell what might be going wrong, from just such a tiny snippet. Please present a proper [mre] of the issue, when asking this kind of question.

Comment: apologies, I was trying to keep it as concise as possible. I have edited my original question to include more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

After much head scratching I have found a solution to the issue. The input box is essentially not recognising that an address has been filled in when grabbing the location from local storage. After changing the value of the input as I did originally I have now added a change event to the field which solves that issue. Updated code below:

```
const saveLocation =
        `<div class="saveLocationWrap">
      <input type="checkbox" id="saveLocation" name="saveLocation">
      <label for="saveLocation">Save my location</label>
      </div>`

searchContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', saveLocation)

/// saveLocation box being the check box I have inserted on page
const saveLocationBox = document.querySelector('#saveLocation')
/// searchBox being the input field
const searchBox = document.querySelector('#locationTextbox')

      saveLocationBox.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (saveLocationBox.checked == true) {
          localStorage.setItem('location', searchBox.value)
        } else {
          console.log('unchecked')
        }
      })


if ('location' in localStorage) {
        searchBox.value = localStorage.getItem('location')
        ***searchBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))***
      }
```